# Meteor-angular2 with Socket.io

Tags: sockets, angular, meteor, angular-meteor, angular2-meteor

I want to include socket.io to my meteor-angular2 app. But I'm finding difficulties to add socket.io/socketjs.

I'm trying to explore this https://github.com/Akryum/meteor-socket-io
but that is not meteor-angular2.

trying this simple code on server/main.ts

> `var io = require('socket.io')(server);
>       io.on('connection', function(socket) {
>           socket.emit('welcome', { message: 'Welcome!', id: socket.id });
>       });`

then this error showed on console

> Error: Cannot find module './client'
>   W20170307-11:49:09.344(7)? (STDERR)     at require
>   (packages\modules-runtime.js:123:19) W20170307-11:49:09.344(7)?
>   (STDERR) at meteorInstall.node_modules.socket.io.lib.index.js
>   (packages\modules.js:1131:14) W20170307-11:49:09.345(7)? (STDERR at
>   fileEvaluate (packages\modules-runtime.js:197:9)
>   W20170307-11:49:09.345(7)? (STDERR) at require
>   (packages\modules-runtime.js:120:16)

Anyone may share config, setup or boilerplate to join meteor-angular2 and socket.io?

Answer (score 0):

To use socket at client side you have to install `socket.io-client` first and then need to import it in your component or service for using it.

Install `socket.io-client` with `npm install socket.io-client --save`.

Import it in Component with `import * as io from 'socket.io-client';`

Connect socket in your component with below code :

```
let socket = io.connect('your socket url', {
  forceNew  : true,
  transports: ['websocket', 'polling', 'flashsocket']
});
```

Comment: how to setup in the server side? i want use my app as server, such as in https://github.com/Akryum/meteor-socket-io